# can't multiply real and integer

Tags: vhdl

I use this code in a testbench, which works as expected:

```
std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(integer(0.603205*(2**16)),16))
```

i want to replace it with a function defined in the same file:

```
function convert_mult(mult : real) return std_logic_vector is
begin       
    
    return std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(integer(mult*(2**16)),16));
    
end function;
```

and call it like this:

```
convert_mult(0.603205)
```

the function fails compilation with "Cannot find the "*" operator with operands denoted with the "[REAL, UNIVERSAL_INTEGER]" signature."

I can't work out whats wrong with this, i thought real * integer was supported? should i be using another type?

Comment: Without looking it up, I can't say either way, but your error message suggests that REAL * INTEGER is not supported. As REAL and INTEGER are _closely related types_ doing a _type conversion_ is easy: `REAL(2)` or `INTEGER(2.0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You can mix real and integer literals like in `0.603205*(2**16)` but not non-literal reals and integer literals like in `mult*(2**16)`. As noted by Matthew, `real` and `integer` are *closely related types*, so converting is easy. Use:

```
return std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(integer(mult*real(2**16)),16));
```

And, incidentally, you write *I thought real * integer was supported*. Well, you were wrong. It is not supported. You must use an explicit conversion... except with literals.

#### Details

Why does it work with literals but not with non-literals? According the VHDL 2008 Language Reference Manual (*IEEE Std 1076-2008*) `universal_integer` and `universal_real` are, respectively, the types of integer and floating point literals.

`0.603205` is a `universal_real`.

`2**16` is a bit more complex because it is an expression involving integer literals (`universal_integer`s). Section *9.3.6 Type conversions* of the LRM  explains that `universal_integer` can be automatically converted to another integer type when needed by the context. I do not know exactly what automatic conversions take place because the LRM is not very easy to follow on this, but I suspect that the `16` is automatically converted to an `integer` according rules of section 9.3.6, which allows the use of the `universal_integer ** integer` operand of package `STANDARD` that returns a `universal_integer` (see section *16.3 Package STANDARD* where all these operators are defined in their functional form).

Finally, section 9.5 *Universal expressions* explicitly states that the `*` operator is defined on `universal_integer * universal_real` and `universal_real * universal_integer`. Both return a `universal_real`.

Note: there is also a `universal_real / universal_integer` returning `universal_real` but no `universal_integer / universal_real`.